# Material UI doesn't use overridden styles when using useTheme hook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use custom theming in Material UI like so:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: PRIMARY_COLOR, // "#121212"
        },
        secondary: {
            main: SECONDARY_COLOR, // "#F7D600"
        },
    },
});


const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
    );
};
```

This works for things like buttons:

```
<Button         
   variant="contained"
   color="secondary"
/>
```

In this case, the hex color `#F7D600` gets applied.

But when I try to use the same color on my components using `makeStyles`, it doesn't seem to recognize it. It just uses the default by Material UI:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  someElement: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main // <- not working. it uses the default purple color
  }
});
```

I also tried `useTheme` but it's the same result:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Box style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main }}></Box>
  );  
}
```

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your import statement, but I use MuiThemeProvider. That could be your issue. Everything else looks right to me

```
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use the below style to override any component in material-UI 
    import { createMuiTheme, colors } from '@material-ui/core'
    
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        background: {
          dark: '#F4F6F8',
          default: colors.common.white,
          paper: colors.common.white,
        },
        primary: {
          main: colors.indigo[500],
        },
        secondary: {
          main: colors.indigo[500],
        },
        text: {
          primary: colors.blueGrey[900],
          secondary: colors.blueGrey[600],
        },
        common: {
          tableHeader: '#DEF3FA',
        },
        action: {
          oddRowColor: '#def3fa2e',
        },
      },
      zIndex: {
        modal: 10010, // override modal zIndex
        appBar: 1000, // override Appbar 
      },
      overrides: { 'MTableHeader-header': { root: { width: '143px !important' } } },
    })

// use in your component 
const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.oddRowColor,//defined in theme
    },
    padding: 'dense',
  },
}))(TableRow)

 [https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/][1]
```